# Normal distribution calculate Percentage for a Z score above 3.4 (not in Z table)

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a normal distribution curve for which I have calculated a Z score of 4, as such I would like to understand the ppm of items outside of my given X value, however the conventional Z table does not go beyond 3.4. How would you calculate beyond this ?

Comment: [Famously](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/), $z>0\implies\frac{z}{1+z^2}<\exp(\tfrac12z^2)\cdot(1-\Phi(z))<\frac1z$. This allows a reasonably accurate estimation of $\Phi(z)$ if $z\gg1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities:

- If you're only supposed to use that particular table, you can report it as "$\gt .9997$", or "$\lt 0.0003$", using whatever the highest value in your table is.
- You can get yourself a better table, from say like [here](https://www.ztable.net/).
- If your question is "how do mathematicians calculate the values for such high $Z$ scores?", someone else will have to answer that.

It's worth mentioning that often the data we have doesn't justify using 4 significant figures, like in my first option, so even though you can get a precise value it can seem a bit silly to report an answer like "$\gt 99.993\%$". You could check with your teacher/adviser to see how they would prefer you to handle such a situation.

Comment: Is it make sense to return 1.0 (100%) for z-score > 4.09 (when the top z-score of the table is 4.09). Why don't they add the value 1.0 but the top value has to be 0.99998?

Comment: @123iamking - the value never actually reaches 1.0, you just get more 9s, e.g. 0.99999995. Also, statistical data always has a little noise on it, and reporting a value of 1.0 makes it look like a sure thing, which it's not, so a value of 1.0 feels a bit deceptive, so we want to discourage people from reporting it.